# How do I get this binary addition program in c++ to work?

Tags: c++, binary

I am trying to create a program that takes in 2 arrays in binary form and calculates the addition of said arrays, although I keep getting the error:

"munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped) "

The code is below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string binaryAddition(int num1[], int num2[]) {


    // BINARY 1: 111011101011
    // BINARY 2: 000000000011


    int carry = 0;
    string res = "";

    for (int i = 11; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (num1[i] == 0 && num2 == 0 && carry == 0) {
            res += "1";
        } else if (num1[i] == 0 && num2[i] == 1 && carry == 0) {
            res += "1";
        } else if (num1[i] == 1 && num2[i] == 0 && carry == 0) {
            res += "1";
        } else if (num1[i] == 1 && num2[i] == 1 && carry == 0) {
            res += "0";
            carry = 1;
        } else if (num1[i] == 0 && num2[i] == 0 && carry == 1) {
            res += "1";
            carry = 0;
        } else if (num1[i] == 0 && num2[i] == 1 && carry == 1) {
            res += "0";
            carry = 1;
        } else if (num1[i] == 1 && num2[i] == 0 && carry == 1) {
            res += "0";
            carry = 1;
        } else if (num1[i] == 1 && num2[i] == 1 && carry == 1) {
            res += "1";
            carry = 1;
        }

    }
    
    cout << res;

}

int main() {

    int num1[12] = {1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1};
    int num2[12] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1};

    binaryAddition(num1, num2);
}
```

Would appreciate some help, Thankyou!

Comment: I'd start by doing something with the result of that function. The purpose of the function appears to be to manufacture a result string, then send sent it back to the caller. Instead, you appear to be manufacturing the string, printing it in the function, and then ignoring the promise you made to return it. Your compiler should be barking a "not all code paths return value..." sort of warning about this. If it doesn't, turn up your warnings. The last line of that proc should be `return res;`

Comment: @WhozCraig That worked! Makes sense to have to return it, thankyou!

Comment: Your first `if` has at least two issues. See if you can find those.

Comment: @RetiredNinja num2 should  = num2[i] and res should += 0, good eye

Answer (score 1):

You can have to calculate the result least significant bit to most significant bit to carry the bit forward.  When you print it then you want go the opposite direction:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string binaryAddition(int num1[], int num2[]) {
    int num3[12] = {};
    int carry = 0;
    for(int i = 11; i >= 0; i--) {
        int sum = num1[i] + num2[i] + carry;
        num3[i] = sum % 2;
        carry = sum / 2;
    }

    string res = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        res += num3[i] ? "1" : "0";
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int num1[] = {1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1};
    int num2[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1};
    cout << binaryAddition(num1, num2) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: So much more simplified, thanks for that advice

Answer (score 0):

You set your `binaryAddition` function to be returning a string but it never returns. So, there are two ways you can do. Either return your res and then cout it in the main:

```
string binaryAddition(int num1[], int num2[]) {
    ...
    return res;
}
int main() {
    ...
    string res = binaryAddition(num1, num2);
    cout << res;
    ...
}
```

Or, you can change its return type to `void`:

```
void binaryAddition(int num1[], int num2[]) {
    ...  // keep the rest
    cout << res;
}
```

Well, you'll need to debug your binaryAddition function and reverse the string too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use bitsets instead. Here is a good example how it could be done
https://alikhuram.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/performing-arithmetic-on-bitsets-in-c/